# pass ng-repeat variable into custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat and a custom directive inside it to which I'm trying to pass the "item" variable from ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
   <div custom-directive custom-data="item"></div>
</li>
```

And imagine a dummy directive:

```
angular.module('someModule').directive('customDirective', function() {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {customData: '@'},
    link: function(scope) {
       console.log(scope.customData);
    }
});
```

- If I use `custom-data="item"` then customData inside the directive
  equals to the string "item".
- If I use `custom-data="{{item}}"` then customData inside the
  directive is a stringified representation of the `item` object and
  the references to other objects inside it are lost.

The question is: how do I pass `item` in the form of object to my directive?

Comment: change `'@'` to `'='`

Answer (score 1):

Change '@' to '=' in your scope assignment then it will work

```
angular.module('someModule').directive('customDirective', function() {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {customData: '='},
    link: function(scope) {
       console.log(scope.customData);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use custom filter in the `ng-repeat` like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list | objectFilter">
   <div custom-directive custom-data="item"></div>
</li>
```

In controller like this

```
'use strict';
filters.filter("objectFilter",function(){
    return function(input){
        angular.forEach(input,function(key,val){
            if(typeof input[val].item == "string"){
                input[val].item = JSON.parse(input[val].item);
            }
        })
        return input;
    }
});
```

So that you get the new set of items with each item now formatted as object.

And finally you have to change the `'@'` to `'='`.Then it works fine.
Simply changing `'@'` to `'=`' doesn't work as you wish.